# Grep: how to match on context?

Tags: grep

Here is the problem, say I have file which looks like this:

```
%% chunk A
#foo{
   %% blah
   more_blah = 1,
   field = f
  }

%% chunk B
#foo{
   %% blah
   more_blah = 1,
   more_blah = 1,
   more_blah = 1,
   more_blah = 1,
   field = f
  }


%% chunk C
#bar{
   field = f
  }
```

I want to find the `field = f`, but only if there is `#foo` within 4 lines before it, e.g., chunk A will match, both chunk B and C won't, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`

```
$ sed -n '/#foo/{N;N;N;N; /field = f/p}' ip.txt 
#foo{
   %% blah
   more_blah = 1,
   field = f
  }
```

- `-n` do not print lines by default
- `/#foo/` string to match
- `N;N;N;N;` get four lines after the matched line
- `/field = f/p` print the 5 lines so obtained if the pattern `/field = f/` is matched

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-A` option of `grep`:

```
grep -A 4 '#foo' file | grep "field = f"
```

`-A 4` will print the `4` lines after the match for every match, so the first part of this command takes the lines after a `#foo`, all that remains is to find the `field = f` in these lines.

Comment: @Sundeep Thank you for the remark! It worked on my zsh with GNU grep and stupidly forgot to test on bash.

Comment: @Sundeep Yep. :) Turns out it is because [zsh by default doesn't interpret `#` as the beginning of a comment like other shells do](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33994/zsh-interpret-ignore-commands-beginning-with-as-comments). Bottom line, always quote in shell scripting kids.